# Webpack magic comments: generate webpackInclude expression dynamically

Tags: angular, webpack

I'd like to write a magic comment (webpackInclude) that is built dynamically; in other words, that evaluates a variable. Something similar to this:

```
const languages = 'es|ar|fr';
/* webpackInclude: /(${languages})\.js$/ */
```

As can be observed, the idea behind this requirement is to load available languages from a list.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can load available languages within a directory. Use [dynamic expressions in import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import). Another option is [`magic-comments-loader`](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader).